# Is encfs safe with Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, encfs

I am using Ubuntu one as my cloud storage and using encfs to encrypt some sensitive data but I am not sure if this is safe?

Can someone, if s/he has my U1 password, download my encrypted data and decrypt them?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this for an insight to ENCFS security.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS#Disadvantages

In answer to your question, all encrypted data can be decrypted. The proviso being how much computer power and time you put to the task of decrypting.

The data is fairly secure as long as the "FBI" doesn't throw their computers at the task. As you are "small fry", no offence, its unlikely that this power will be used on your data.

You can use other encryption systems that take longer to decrypt like `truecrypt` but in the end its just time and power. Theoretically in ten years when computers go "quantum" all this data will be trivial to decrypt.